# strings and numbers in comparisons in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
var result='16'>'141';
console.log(result);
```

```js
var result='16'>141;
console.log(result);
```

> That’s because if any of the operands is not string, then both
>   operands become numbers, and the comparison becomes correct.

Can anyone tell me. How below equation is evaluate?

```js
var result='a'>11;
console.log(result);
```

```
'a'>11=> Answer should be true instead of false;
```

because 
 `'a' will convert to int 97 > 11 => true` then how it evaluate `false`.
If I go like this `'a'>'11' => then it answer comes true`.

```js
var result='a'>'11';
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: _"'a' will convert to int 97"_ __NO__ `Number('a')` will be `NaN` and `NaN` is never equals to anything including itself..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you convert a non-numeric string like `'a'` to a Number, you get `NaN`:

```js
console.log(+'a');        // NaN
console.log('a' * 1);     // NaN
console.log(Number('a')); // NaN
```

And `NaN` always produces `false` in relational comparisons. [Trichotomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichotomy_(mathematics)) does not hold:

```js
console.log(NaN < 0);  // false
console.log(NaN > 0);  // false
console.log(NaN == 0); // false
```

If you want to convert `'a'` to `97`, use `charCodeAt`:

```js
console.log('a'.charCodeAt(0)); // 97
```

Comment: Few of the readers may not know that `Unary plus` acts as `Number()`

Answer (score 0):

Javscript use **The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm**

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

When comparing a string and a number, string is converted to a number, but you are thinking like some ASCII code.

Since 'a' is not a number so it's comparison with a number will give you false in any case `>` , `<` or `==`.